# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am getting this exception  `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7  and java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache`) when i run the spring boot application

I am using below tools

***STS 3.9.10 release 

Open JDK 14 64 bit 

Spring boot 2.2.5***

It worked fine with oracle jdk but its failing to run with openjdk.  I am not using any groovy libs. This is maven based spring boot project.

Comment: You should clarify which build tool you're using.

Answer (score 192):

How do you run the application? It's probably because you use Gradle as the build system and JDK14 and the Gradle version is old.
Reference: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/10248

If you use Gradle Wrapper then refer to `$PROJECT_ROOT/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`. The property `distributionUrl` should be:
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-bin.zip`

If it's an older version then change it, run `./gradlew clean build` and try again.

Comment: Thanks so much, I tried many things trying to get React Native working on my machine.  This did the trick!

Comment: To follow up on this, I'm using maven and `brew` upgraded me to OpenJDK 14 recently, so I started getting this error. From this answer's link to the gradle issue, I found this groovy issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-9211 which has since been fixed in Groovy 2.5.10 -- so make sure you upgrade your groovy version to that one or newer. Solved the issue for me!

Comment: And use gradle-7.0-bin.zip for Java **16**  --   "As of Gradle 7.0, both running Gradle itself and building JVM projects with Java **16** is fully supported." https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/release-notes.html

Comment: Here are the highlights of Gradle 6.3 Release:
 1) Java 14 support. 
 2) Improved error messages for unexpected failures.

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/release-notes.html

Comment: For latest gradle release available, see here- https://gradle.org/install/

Comment: @pennstatephil Thanks. Upgrading from 2.5.9 to 2.5.10 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 66):

I solved it by editing the  *gradle-wrapper.properties* file inside the *gradle* folder. (Not .gradle) :

Change this line, from:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.2-all.zip
```

to:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip
```

rebuild and it's ok.

Answer (score 52):

In the file `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`, ensure that the `distributionUrl` is as follows:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-bin.zip
```

Note: If you installed jdk 14

Answer (score 16):

Got the same issue on a Maven & SpringBoot project, no Gradle whatever.

The dependency to org.codehaus.groovy is probably transitive through spring-cloud-contract-verifier. Run `mvn dependency:tree` to view the whole dependency tree.

I got it fixed by upgrading the spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin version to 2.2.3-RELEASE

Answer (score 11):

in my maven Spring Boot project, I solve the problem by adding dependency:

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

Check that your project is running with Java 14 even though it is prepared for Java 8.

My IntelliJ Idea was giving the same error when trying to execute a Gradle task which was running perfectly in command line with JDK 8. The ItelliJ Idea project default JDK was 14 though.

Answer (score 7):

in my case, the JRE version used in the **Run Configuration** was different than the target JDK version in the pom.xml

[image: SpringBoot_Run_Config]

Comment: This is definitely the scope for my problem. For me though, I just need to change the JRE from any of the one I have installed to simply "Bundled". CMIIW but it seems that I have correctly install the project with `mvn clean install`, and then maybe Bundled means I just use my installed bundle instead of the installed JRE/JDK on my machine. But really CMIIW. This works for me.

Answer (score 4):

I resolve this problem when integrated Facebook **7.19.2** and Google play Games **0.10.09**.

In my case JDK and SDK using (and other in `Edit/Preferences/External -> Tools-Android`) default paths Unity:

JDK

```
C:/ProgramFiles/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.2.12f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools\OpenJDK\Windows
```

SDK

```
C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.2.12f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer\SDK
```

In Environmental Variables(System Proporites/Advanced) added next:

Find(or click new variable under User Variables)

- `JAVA_HOME` and add root JDK path.
- `JAVA_BIN` and add path JDK/bin
- `JAVA_LIB` and add path JDK/lib

Also, add these paths in System Variables to variable "Path".

Do not use SDK from default Unity and JDK from not Unity default

Then Restart Unity(and better PC).

Then in Editor Unity - `Assets/Play -> Service -> Resolve/Android -> Resolver/Force -> Resolve`

All Work fine.

Answer (score 4):

In my case the combination was IntelliJ 2020.2, Kotlin 1.3.72, Maven 3.6.1 and SpringBoot 2.2.1 application. No Gradle used at all in the project.

Somehow IntelliJ had switched to use OpenJDK14 - when reverting back to OpenJDK11 everything started to work again.

Comment: Reverting the JDK version that had accidentally been bumped up did the trick for me as well.

Answer (score 4):

4 things in IntelliJ to check:

- Your Project Structure -> Project -> SDK and Language level
- Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle, look at Gradle JVM
- Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler
- Your build.gradle, the Java { sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility }

Make them all agree on the JDK / language level and it should be fine

Answer (score 3):

are you using some third party library that brings in **org.codehaus.groovy** dependencies? If yes, you can try and replace the required groovy dependencies with the most current releases yourself.

In my case it was the **org.liquibase:liquibase-groovy-dsl**,
so I did this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-groovy-dsl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                <artifactId>groovy-sql</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-sql</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by adding [Apache Groovy 2.4.7](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy/2.4.7) in pom.xml

Comment: thanks so much! this saved me some time! I couldn't get it to work in a very specific context and - tried all solutions mentioned here, with various version combinations and was just about to break something

Answer (score 2):

For Maven users, Please follow the below steps to resolve this issue

1. You should place rest-assured before the JUnit dependency declaration in your pom.xml / build.gradle in order to make sure that the correct version of Hamcrest is used.
2. Add the following dependencies to your pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.8</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.8</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-json -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-json</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope this will fix your issue. It works for me. Instruction mentioned at step#1 copies from Rest Assured official site. Thanks

Comment: Didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by selecting Installed JRE path in window => preferences => java => installed JRE => remve existing & select from local directory.

Make sure you have java_home variable set in environmental variable

Answer (score 1):

I simply changed the gradle version for the project to the newer version.

[image: a screenshot of the upgrade]

PS. I use kotlin

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for similar solution as @godsim shared, but for gradle liquabase plugin, then modify your configuration section in build.gradle to exclude liquabase's groovy dependency:

```
configurations {
    ...
    liquibaseRuntime.exclude group: "org.codehaus.groovy"
}
```

and then manually add groovy in dependencies section:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    liquibaseRuntime('org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.8.1')
    liquibaseRuntime('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.3')
    liquibaseRuntime 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    liquibaseRuntime('org.liquibase:liquibase-groovy-dsl:2.1.2')
    liquibaseRuntime('org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-hibernate5:3.10.2')
    liquibaseRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    liquibaseRuntime sourceSets.main.output
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved for me only when I updated compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 30 with minSdkVersion 19

Answer (score 0):

Was getting the error when using old versions of `spotbugs-maven-plugin` plugin and the corresponding `spotbugs` maven dependency.

Fixed by upgrading both to `4.2.0`.

Answer (score 0):

It was coming for me in Idea, and got resolved after setting JAVA_HOME in .zshrc and .bash_profile, source both the files and restart the Idea.

```
export JAVA_HOME="<Path to JDK just above bin " # For e.g it was "/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11" in my Mac machine could be /Contents/Home based on you have used homebrew or manually gunzipped
```

Comment: JAVA_HOME is not typically required to compile the android project because the jdk is set for android lib

Answer (score 0):

It can also happen because you forgot to indicate your Android SDK via local.properties in a freshly cloned Android Project.

Answer (score 0):

I had to work on a project with Gradle version 6.0.1. First I wanted to update the Gradle wrapper while then later I got other issues. So to stay with Gradle wrapper 6.0.1, I had to downgrade Java version from 17 to 8.

In **Eclipse** I had to override workspace settings in the Advanced section with setting explicitly Java home. Otherwise the project wouldn't load at all.

[image]

In **IntelliJ IDEA** the case was that project could open while it presented following error.

[image]

Again I had to downgrade Java version to 8 from 17 in the Gradle build window:
[image]

For a long shot it definitely makes sense to upgrade the project.

Answer (score -1):

I have met a similar problem. But my error message is not exactly the same.

I got some ideas from Tarmo and checking the gradle version, eclipse version and the JDK it use.

My error message is:

```
> Could not open cp_init generic class cache for initialization script 'D:\xxx\TestingEnv\Dev1\eclipse\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.buildship.core\init.d\eclipsePlugin.gradle' (C:\Users\xxx\.gradle\caches\5.6\scripts\6a5krabdzij62jglcll542e66\cp_init\cp_init8a51e2ebf3f7f8302cfbbb80ea3d4b3d).
   > Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.Verifier
```

I have using
SpringToolSuite4
**Version: 4.9.0.RELEASE Build Id: 202012132054** for development.

I have 2 projects. Project A and Project B.

Project A, works fine without gradle problem
Under this project, gradle> wrapper > gradle-wrapper.propties
My distributionUrl is:
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.8-bin.zip

Later, I have another project B and the setting is:

Project B:
Under this project, gradle> wrapper > gradle-wrapper.propties
My distributionUrl is:
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-bin.zip

When I select 'refresh gradle' in the IDE, Project B keeps failing build and output the error mentioned above.

I have no clues on it until I found the answer from Tarmo.

Things I have done:

1. Try to change the distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-bin.zip
   -The error message changes to other. (Seems we are on the right way)
2. Check the JDK version, which Eclipse using to start the itself.

- Under menu bar > Help > About Spring Tool Suite 4 > Installation Details > press 'Configuration Tab >
  searching for a row start with -vm
- It was originally pointing th OpenJDK, then I changed it to pointing to JDK 1.8 at my local machine. It failed to start since it is not supported the older version of JDK.

3. I downloaded the older version of STS **sts-4.4.1.RELEASE**

- Now, I import the project again, press 'refresh gradle', it works fine and the gradle task shows properly in the IDE.

4. In the sts-4.4.1.RELEASE folder, adding an entry into SpringToolSuite4.ini to pointing to use JDK 1.8 at my local PC.

```
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_301/bin/javaw.exe
```

-If not specify, it would use the openjdk to start with by default. It is a good practice to specify the version we use.

Appendix
SpringToolSuite4.ini
https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Answer (score -3):

If you are on Windows operating system and using Android Studio, you should run Android Studio as Administrator.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Android. Also, tips like "Run XYZ as Administrator" are usually not helpful.

Answer (score -8):

Move to JDK 11, it should work.

Comment: Making sure that the versions of Groovy and Java are compatible is probably the right answer - I was trying to run Groovy 2 with Java 21 and got this error - updating to Groovy 4 fixed the issue.