# "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7" error when I try to run a REST Assured test class

Tags: eclipse, maven, rest-assured

I have JDK 1.8 installed and below is the class I run in Eclipse:

```java
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RestAssured.baseURI = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";
        given()
               .queryParam("posts", "1")
               .body("")
        .when()
               .get()
        .then()
               .assertThat().statusCode(200)
               .body("userId", equalTo(2));
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.VMPluginFactory.<clinit>(VMPluginFactory.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.GroovyClassValueFactory.<clinit>(GroovyClassValueFactory.java:35)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.<clinit>(ClassInfo.java:107)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache.getCachedClass(ReflectionCache.java:95)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache.<clinit>(ReflectionCache.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.registerMethods(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:209)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:107)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:85)
    at groovy.lang.GroovySystem.<clinit>(GroovySystem.java:36)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.<clinit>(InvokerHelper.java:86)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.createMap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:635)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseParserRegistrar.<init>(ResponseParserRegistrar.groovy)
    at io.restassured.RestAssured.<clinit>(RestAssured.java:346)
    at test.main(test.java:12)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgmimpl.NumberNumberMetaMethod.<clinit>(NumberNumberMetaMethod.java:33)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:350)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:645)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.createMetaMethodFromClass(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:257)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:85)
    at groovy.lang.GroovySystem.<clinit>(GroovySystem.java:36)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.<clinit>(InvokerHelper.java:86)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.createMap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:635)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseParserRegistrar.<init>(ResponseParserRegistrar.groovy)
    at io.restassured.RestAssured.<clinit>(RestAssured.java:346)
    at test.main(test.java:12)
```

Comment: Refer the answer of @BertKoor in this post [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61289461/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-org-codehaus-groovy-v)

Answer (score 0):

Run `mvn dependency:tree` to view the whole dependency tree. You check if you see a problem here.

And try upgrading the **maven-plugin version**.