# i got this error message when running my flutter project

Tags: java, flutter, gradle

this is the error message : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7
it turns later to another error : Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61289461/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-org-codehaus-groovy-v

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by changing `gradle-wrapper.properties`, `distributionUrl` to-

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-bin.zip
```