# Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache when running gradlew.bat file

Tags: java, gradle, windows-10, gradlew

I am trying to run a gradlew.bat file via cmd and am running into the error:

```
Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper
> Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache [in thread "Daemon worker"]
```

I tried following various solutions from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61289461/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-org-codehaus-groovy-v) to no avail. I tried changing the value in gradle-wrapper.properties from

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1-bin.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-bin.zip
```

and ran again but was met with:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'nexus-deploy'.
> Could not open cp_proj remapped class cache for s5e1jtxdcnwfq13zlj7qke7c
```

I then tried removing the scripts + scripts-remapped folders from the gradle cache but that did nothing as well. Finally, I tried running

```
./gradlew clean
```

but got

```
   * What went wrong:
   A problem occurred configuring root project 'nexus-deploy'.
   Could not open cp_proj remapped class cache for s5e1jtxdcnwfq13zlj7qke7c
```

I'm not sure what is going wrong and don't know what else to try. I am on java version "1.8.0_341" and Gradle 7.5.1.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Any solution yet?

Comment: Solution is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61509462/158257

Answer (score 6):

check if jdk 18 is supported in Android. I am using jdk 11 and NDK 21.3

Answer (score 2):

my problem was the issue of the environment variable "JAVA_HOME", I updated to jdk 11, as it was in the latest jdk, after updating it fixed my problem

Answer (score 2):

Maybe has another Java version in your computer.
[Gradle compatible with java reference.](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#compatibility)
Upgrade gradle version to the supported Java version in your computer.

Answer (score 1):

Just switched my java version to jdk 8 & worked for my case. **Try Changing your jdk versions and find out which works the best**. In my case, while using FVM(flutter version manager) , after a week I found that using jdk 8 was working for the older project I was working on despite newer java version worked for my newer projects but not for older projects.